# What's the correct or proper way to read RFCs on HTTP?

Tags: http, rfc

From Wikipedia:

"The first definition of HTTP/1.1, the version of HTTP in common use, occurred in **RFC 2068** in 1997, although this was obsoleted by **RFC 2616 in 1999** and then again by **RFC 7230 and family** in 2014."

<strike>"The HTTP/2 specification was published as **RFC 7540** in May 2015."</strike>

Should I then read all the RFCs in the mentioning order or just the newest 'RFC 7230 and family'(what family?) because it contains all information already sorted out?

Generally are RFCs updates incremental or fully-merged?

Comment: I cannot definitively answer this, but I would expect that if you read the latest version and it has references to previous versions and/or builds on previous versions, that this should be [made] readily obvious to the reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) (and family, by which is meant the other RFC723x HTTP RFCs):

> This document is the
> first in a series of documents that collectively form the HTTP/1.1
> specification:

> 1. "Message Syntax and Routing" (this document)

> 2. "Semantics and Content" [RFC7231]

> 3. "Conditional Requests" [RFC7232]

> 4. "Range Requests" [RFC7233]

> 5. "Caching" [RFC7234]

> 6. "Authentication" [RFC7235]

Obsoleted means that the previous version no longer applies, and should not need to be referred to or quoted (and, especially, shouldn't be quoted in support of answers you may give on SO :-))

Comment: an then, if you're interested in HTTP/2, RFC 7540 and 7541 as well.

Comment: @JulianReschke - correct, but I chose to just stick to HTTP/1.1, despite the tagging, given the current striking-through of that mention in the question.

Comment: Removed that tag.  But still very helpful to know.